# JS function not returning value

Tags: javascript

I have this function in Game.js

```
Game.prototype.onClick = function(event){
     var x = event.x;
     var y = event.y;
     if (this.blueDeck[0].contains(x, y)) 
       alert("Blue Deck Clicked");
}
```

*OnClick* gets called from this function in Main.js

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', game.onClick, false);
```

and I have this function in Card.js

```
Card.prototype.contains = function(x, y){
    return true;
}
```

The alert never comes up.

If I remove the if statement in *onClick*, the alert gets called.
Other functions like `this.blueDeck[0].setDeckPos(w, h);` work fine when called in Game.js.

Why is *contains* not returning true?

Comment: Are you sure `this` refers to what you want it to? How/when are you calling the `onClick` method? `this` probably refers to something else (like the DOM element, which I'd assume this method is bound to) which does not have a `blueDeck` property and therefore throws an error. `contains` for sure returns `true`.

Comment: tip: beware of closures in js

Comment: You need to post a "working" example that demonstrates the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update confirms my assumption. `this` will refer to the DOM element. The value of `this` is determined on runtime, i.e. it depends on *how* the function is called, not where/how it was defined.

Either use a closure:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    game.onClick(event);
}, false);
```

or if you don't need access to the element, you can use [`.bind` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (see this link for a polyfill for browser with no native support):

```
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', game.onClick.bind(game), false);
```

Learn more about `this`:

- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (general)
- [quirksmode.org - `this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) (emphasis on event handlers)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of the OP works, so the error is elsewhere:

```
function Game(){
  this.blueDeck = [new Card()];
}

Game.prototype.onClick = function(event){
     var x;
     var y;
     if (this.blueDeck[0].contains(x, y)) 
       alert("Blue Deck Clicked");
}

function Card(){}

Card.prototype.contains = function(x, y){
    return true;
}

var g = new Game();
g.onClick(); // "Blue Deck Clicked"
```

### Edit

When editing questions, please clearly mark the edit. See Felix's answer, the method isn't being called by an instance of Game but by an event listener. Remember that *this* is set by the call.